# While not (x==x) vs. while (x!=x)

Tags: python

I was doing an assignment for a class, namely:

Given a set of N measurements, (r1, r2, . . . , rN ), we will initially assign the odd-numbered measurements to class 1 and the even numbered measurements to class 2. Then the following two steps are repeated:

• Update step: Compute the mean value (average) of the measurements within each cluster.
• Assignment step: Assign each measurement to the cluster with the closest mean value.

In case of a tie, assign the measurement to cluster 1.
Repeat the above steps until the cluster assignments do not change. It can not be determined in advance how many steps will be needed before the clustering assignment stabilizes.

the code i used to solve this originally but unsuccesfully was:

```
import numpy as np
def clusterAnalysis(reflectance):

    oldCluster=np.zeros(np.size(reflectance))

    Cluster=(np.arange(0,np.size(reflectance))%2)+1

    while np.all(oldCluster!=Cluster):
        oldCluster=np.copy(Cluster)

        m1=np.mean(reflectance[Cluster==1])
        m2=np.mean(reflectance[Cluster==2])

        for i in range(np.size(reflectance)):
            d1= abs(reflectance[i]-m1)
            d2= abs(reflectance[i]-m2)
            if d1<=d2:
                Cluster[i]=1
            else:
                Cluster[i]=2

    return Cluster
```

this did not work. however, when i replaced

```
while np.all(oldCluster!=Cluster):
```

with:

```
while not np.all(oldCluster==Cluster):
```

it did work!

can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: What is the difference between "while all are not equal" and "while not all are equal"? The first requires all values to be different, while the second just one difference is enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same. This:

```
while np.all(oldCluster!=Cluster):
```

should read:

```
while not np.any(oldCluster==Cluster):
```

More here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws